# Skips over code

Tags: java

The problem occurs in the seventh section. It will not allow me to read in a state and instead prints the else statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ifElseStatements
{
   public static Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      one();
      two();
      three();
      four();
      five();
      six();
      seven();
      eight();
   }
   public static void one()
   {
   System.out.print("grade: ");
   int number = in.nextInt();
   if(number > 70 && number <=100)
   {
      System.out.println("You're passing");
   }
   else
   {
      System.out.println("you're not passing!");
   }

   }  

   public static void two()
   {
      System.out.print("Number please");
      int b = in.nextInt();
      if(b <=50)
      {
      System.out.println("Go");
      }
      else
      {
      System.out.println("STOP");
      }
   }

   public static void three()
   {
      System.out.print("Integer please >");
      int c = in.nextInt();
      if(c%2 == 0)
      {
         System.out.println("Even");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("odd");
      }
   }

   public static void four()
   {
      System.out.print("Integer please");
      int d = in.nextInt();
      if(d%5 == 0)
      {
         System.out.println("Multiple of 5");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Not a multiple of 5");
      }
   }

   public static void five()
   {
      System.out.print("number please");
      int e = in.nextInt();
      if(e< 10)
      {
         System.out.println("one digit");
      }
      else if(e>= 10 && e<100)
      {
         System.out.println("two digits");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("three digits");
      }
   }

   public static void six()
   {
      System.out.print("Jersey Number");
      int f = in.nextInt();
      if(f == 12 || f == 80 || f == 71)
      {
         System.out.println("That number is retired from the seattle seahawks");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("");
      }

   } 

   public static void seven()
   {
      System.out.print("a state is");
      String g = in.nextLine();
      if(g .equals ("Washington") || g .equals ("Oregon") || g .equals ("Idaho"))
      {
         System.out.println("That state is in the PNW!");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("You should move to the PNW; Its great here!");
      }
   }  

   public static void eight()
   {
      System.out.print("drink size (SHORT, TALL, GRANDE, VENTI)");
      String h = in.nextLine();
      if(h .equals ("SHORT"))
      {
         System.out.println("8");
      }
      else if(h .equals ("TALL"))
      {
         System.out.println("12");
      }
      else if(h .equals ("GRANDE"))
      {
         System.out.println("16");
      }
      else if(h .equals ("VENTI"))
      {
         System.out.println("20");
      }
   }


}
```

This is what it looks like when I run the code.

```
grade: 70

you're not passing!

Number please12

Go

Integer please >30

Even

Integer please15

Multiple of 5

number please33

two digits

Jersey Number12

That number is retired from the seattle seahawks

a state isYou should move to the PNW; Its great here!

drink size (SHORT, TALL, GRANDE, VENTI)TALL

12 oz
```

Comment: If it's in the seventh section why did you put a hundred lines of code here rather than just those relevant 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous step just does `in.nextInt()`, which reads the next int, but doesn't consume the EOL character. So, the step7 method reads the next line, and consumes the EOL that hasn't been consumed by the previous step.

You should add `in.nextLine()` in step6 to consume the EOL character, and not just the integer.

Comment: +1 The OP typed `12<enter>` not just `12` and this `<enter>` is being read by seven()'s nextLine();

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue resulting from you using both `Scanner.nextInt()` and `Scanner.nextLine()`, which doesn't always work as you would want it to. You can find an explanation for this by going through [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to get an idea how Scanners work, but for a simple fix just replace instances of

```
in.nextInt();
```

with

```
Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

Comment: Indeed it would, although I find this solution safer.